# Adding angular animate to pre-existing stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, dependencies, gulp, dependency-management

I've cloned this repo: https://github.com/Hyra/Frickle 
Its quite awesome! But I'm trying to add more angular modules and I'm not succeeding.

In the main directory I run **npm install angular-animate**. This adds the angular-animate folder files to the node_modules folder within the project right alongside the other angular modules and the angular library itself.

In the package.json file, I've added to the dependencies angular-animate by adding the following

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.5",
...
```

In main.js

```
'use strict';

require('angular');

var uiRoute = require('angular-ui-router');
var ngAnimate = require('angular-animate');
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [uiRoute, ngAnimate]);
```

Angular-ui-router works fine in the original setup. The stack uses gulp and browserify to concatenate and minify the javascript files but as I'm kind of new to angular, I'm not sure why I'm having issues adding a simple dependency to this stack. Hopefully this is simple and someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

The error I get in the console is as follows:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks really strange: `var app = angular.module('MyApp', [uiRoute, ngAnimate]);`

According to: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/function/angular.module

The `requires` array is supposed to be an array of strings. So it should really be:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [uiRoute.name, ngAnimate.name]);
```